# Shopify error code with reCAPTCHA – "Parameter Missing or Invalid: Required parameter missing or invalid: customer"

Tags: parameters, shopify, recaptcha

Keep getting this error code when attempting to register account on Shopify. Go to register, enter details and PW, then after clicking 'I'm not a robot' clicking appropriate images and submit, the error code appears.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eduoc.png)

Comment: Did you find a solution?